# could not locate named parameter: Using setParameterList

Tags: sql, hibernate

I am getting following error:

```
org.hibernate.QueryParameterException: could not locate named parameter [projects]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.ParameterMetadata.getNamedParameterDescriptor(ParameterMetadata.java:148)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.ParameterMetadata.getNamedParameterExpectedType(ParameterMetadata.java:165)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractQueryImpl.determineType(AbstractQueryImpl.java:523)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractQueryImpl.setParameterList(AbstractQueryImpl.java:892)
    at com.pepsico.trackwise.sqa.job.ActivityProcessor.execute(ActivityProcessor.java:117)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:207)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:560)
```

This my Query:

```
<sql-query name="findRecordsByPerson">
    <return-scalar column="prId" type="java.lang.Integer"/>

    SELECT pr.id AS prId
    FROM pr
    INNER JOIN project pj ON pr.project_id=pj.id
    INNER JOIN pr_addtl_data PAD ON pr.id=PAD.pr_id
    INNER JOIN data_fields df ON df.id=PAD.data_field_id
    WHERE df.field_class IN (7, 16)
      AND PAD.n_value = :pid
      AND pj.name IN (:projects)
    UNION
    SELECT pr.id AS prId
    FROM pr
    INNER JOIN project pj ON pr.project_id=pj.id
    WHERE originator_rel_id=:pid
      AND pj.name IN (:projects)

</sql-query>
```

This is my code:

```
List prList = db.getNamedQuery("findRecordsByPerson")
                                .setInteger("pid", pid)
                                .setParameterList("projects", Arrays.asList(new String[]{Constants.PROJECT_SUPPLIER_SITE, Constants.PROJECT_SUPPLIER_SITE_APPROVAL,
                                        Constants.PROJECT_SUPPLIER_SITE_AUDIT, Constants.PROJECT_SUPPLIER_SITE_MATERIAL}))
                                .list();
```

I have checked all available answers give in this forum. Syntactically i find my code correct m not sure what is missing here. Please help.

Comment: Your SQL seems good. Have you tried writing `(:projects)` without brackets in your XML?

Comment: Thanks for response @Raman Sahasi 
Still error persists.As in query there are 4 parameters(projects twice,pid twice) Do i need to set those 4 parameters?